# return dropdown list via ajax function call

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I'm trying to return an arraylist via ajax function call and return the results to my HTML dropdown list.
Below is my ajax function, servlet code and html.
My dropdown list keeps coming back empty.  Not sure where it is going wrong.

Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Integer p = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("studentid"));

    ArrayList<SessionDataBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String sessid = null;
    try ( Connection con = JdbcUtil.getConnection()) {
        String sql= "select distinct F.SESSIONID "
                + "from Students F "
                + "where F.studentid = "+p;
        try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
            System.out.println(sql);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()){
                result.add(new SessionDataBean(rs.getString(1)));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    new Gson().toJson(result, response.getWriter()); 

    }
```

Ajax function call code:

```
function listSession(){
  var name = document.getElementById("studentid").value;      
  $.ajax({
        url : "<%=context%>/ListSessionsServlet?studentid=" + name,
        type : "POST",
        async : false,
        dataType: "json",
          success : function(data) {
              var toAppend = '';
              $.each(data,function(i,o){
                  toAppend += '<option>'+o.id+'</option>';  <---issue might be here?
                 });

                $('#sessid').append(toAppend);
          }  
    });
 }
```

HTML code:

```
    <div class="cell">
        Select Session for Student
        <div class="input-control select mutiple full-size">
            <select id="sessid" name="sessid">
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *Not sure where it is going wrong.* That's what debugging is for.

Comment: your ajax call could not be functioning currently. the append looks good enough. Try adding an `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    } ` to your ajax call. Also a check for null data in your success

Answer (score 1):

Server is expecting a `POST` parameter `"studentid"` at

`Integer p = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("studentid"));`

though `"name"` is passed. Substitute

`url : "<%=context%>/ListSessionsServlet?studentid=" + name`

for

`url : "<%=context%>/ListSessionsServlet?name=" + name`

Comment: dropdown list is still empty.

Comment: @thedude865 The parameter at `success` is `list`, though you pass `data` , which is `undefined`, to `$.each()`?

Comment: Should o.id inside '<option>'+o.id+'</option>', be something else?

Comment: @ guest271314 yep, I corrected that issue...it is now "data" in both areas

Comment: @thedude865 Not that can determine, though should be `$.each(list,function(i,o){})` where `list` is substituted for `data`

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` log at `console`?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson,  but I added the external jar file to my build path, maybe it needs to be in a different folder structure?

Comment: import com.google.gson.Gson;    seems to be added in my class file

Comment: ok.  I got it working.  Had to place GSON jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Christ.